# Can an English sentence exist without the subject?

Tags: sentence-construction, syntax, subjects

In the bold sentence below, I can't find the subject, and I think it's not a inverted sentence. I don't know if it's right?

> **Particularly relevant to the present work is the recent paper of Verdun et al.**, where quantum learning of parametrised unitary operations is carried out coherently.

Comment: There is a  reverse subject.

Comment: [Yes,](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/yes)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The recent **paper** of Verdun et al is particularly relevant to the present work, where [rest of clause].

- subject phrase: The recent paper of Verdun et al
- subject: paper

**This sentence's order has been reversed** in order to emphasize the idea of "being particularly relevant". This technique is generally only used with the verb be.

- The tree on the hill is especially interesting to us.

can be:

- Especially interesting to us is the tree on the hill.

Here is a technical explanation of this reversal, also known as anastrophe:

[anastrophe](https://www.enotes.com/homework-help/what-reversed-sentence-structure-shakespeare-475084#:%7E:text=Reversion%20of%20the%20word%20order,retain%20the%20meter%20or%20rhyme.)